# How to exclude a field when a search is done?

Tags: search

I just enable the **Search Form** (provide by the search module) block to allow the visitor to make searches.

When a search is done the entered word is searched in all field of the nodes.

Can I exclude a field?

Let's say the content type has the fields: **title**, **body** and **provider**.

Then when a search is done I need to exclude the field **provider** from the search.

I have the custom_search module enabled but I see no way to exclude fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default Search is not customizable. Consider using one of more advanced solutions:

- [Search API](https://drupal.org/project/search_api) with client module that will suit your needs.
- [Finder](https://drupal.org/project/finder) with proper views configuration.

Comment: I was sure last line of question wasn't there when I answered. Strange.

Comment: but OP not made any edit, not possible

Comment: Of all the people here, you should know that [edits are not always visible](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/look-like-bug-in-suggested-edit)

Comment: i know because i posted the question, may be this one different, please don't mistake me

Comment: thanks Molot. As far as I see the Search Api is the right way to do this